# Maximum allowable height in pixels, CSS

Tags: css, cross-browser, size, pixel

I understand that different browsers are likely to have different ceiling values, but what is a good rule of thumb for the maximum render-able CSS height/width in a given browser?

For example, this trick:

```
.parent{
    overflow: hidden;
}

.column{
    float: left;
}

.max-height{
    margin-bottom: -30000px;
    padding-bottom: 30000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

    <div class="column">
    </div>

    <!-- given a background color, this div will appear to expand to 100% the
         parent height -->
    <div class="column max-height">
    </div>

</div>
```

I know it's nearly stupid, but if a page were to expand beyond `30000px`, now the trick doesn't work.

I've seen `32768px` used in various places; is this due to higher values being unreliable, or just because its a nice square number?

Comment: Just curious, in what application would you need beyond 30000px for height?

Comment: Opera has a restriction of 32,766 pixels (2^15 - 2).

Comment: @ngen: Stuff that scrolls infinitely with enough content.

Comment: @BoltClock: Nice, fair enough.

Comment: @BoltClock - That's probably where that value comes from, I've also seen `65535px` (2^16-1) thrown around too (*though not as often, probably due to Opera*) So is (2^15-1) the rule then?

Comment: @BoltClock, In reference to @ ngen.  In such a case you don't want to use infinite pixels worth of space.  You would want to reuse the space that is out of view, and if you were really conservative, you would never use more than the users window size x 2.

Comment: @ngen & Joseph - Yes, it is absurd (*most typically*) that a given page would inherently be, or expand to, such a size. However I'm just being proactive, and am curious about any limitations. (*Mind you, I've seen some docs pages that are pretty damn long. Check Kohana's API docs; http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Database_Query_Builder_Select is `30931px` tall.*)

Comment: IE6/7 use active-x, which uses a 12-bit size register = 4906

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be tempted to have a look at what values can be returned from javascript in the screen object available height

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     document.write("Available Height: " + screen.availHeight);
     document.write("Available Width: " + screen.availWidth);

    </script>
```

Using jquery you could set the body height and width to these values using the .css function if you pass them in as variables such as.

```
var screenHeight = screen.availHeight
```

of course this assumes if javascript is enabled on the clients browser

Comment: Thank you for mentioning _avail_ props, perfect for different devices and they do relate to each screen's available space. _screen.height_ and _screen.width_ include constant non-available amounts and are different from _window.innerHeight_ and _window.innerWidth_ (which change with resizes).